# Is it possible to change the base dn of a user in ldap using java?

Tags: java, ldap, ldap-query

My requirement is to migrate the users from ou=people,dc=agroup,dc=com
to dc=1a_archive,dc=com using java
i just want to know if this is possible? if possible please tell me the solution

Comment: It depends on the server and which backend is being used, it could help to provide these details in the first place.. as @jwilleke mentioned some backend won't let you move an entry with children.

Answer (score 1):

Using the LDAP protocol this requires a [ModRDN](https://ldapwiki.com/wiki/Modrdn) that would "move" the LDAP Entry. (See link for some examples)

Oracle also shows some simple JNDI examples using [Context.rename()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jndi/ldap/rename.html)

Most LDAP Server Implementations do NOT support the ModifyDNRequest on an LDAP Entry which contain subordinate entries.

Some LDAP Server Implementation include a method to move containers. I am aware the these support moving containers, perhaps with some limitations:

- Microsoft Active Directory
- eDirectory

Comment: my requirement is from this base dn ou=people,dc=agroup,dc=com i have fetch a user based on some attribute eg: email attribute is not null and i have to  move those users to new base dn "dc=com to dc=1a_archive,dc=com" using java. Is it possible with java code? if yes please provide the solution

Comment: Use the ModRDN LDAP Operation. See the JNDI examples using Context.rename()

Comment: can we pass base value of ldap server to get connection with ldap using java code?